# Is it possible to create new custom permissions in wso2 identity server 5.9

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server

Hi I am newbie to Wso2 identity server ,using server version `5.9`. I can able to add new users and new roles.Is it possible to add custom permissions that are not in the default list.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few possible ways for you to add custom permissions in the WSO2 identity server.

**Method 01:**

You can create a service provider and add application-specific permissions to the current registry permission tree. To see how you can do this please refer to [[1]](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Roles+and+Permissions+for+a+Service+Provider).

**Method 02:**

You can add new permissions to the existing permission tree through the registry browse in the Management Console. To see how you can follow this approach please refer to [[2]](http://gknamarathna.blogspot.com/2018/01/customizing-permissions-for-wso2.html).

**Method 03:**

You can also add custom permissions to the registry through a programmatical approach. To see how you can do this please refer to [[3]](http://shazninazeer.blogspot.com/2014/10/adding-new-permissions-to-permission.html).