# In wso2 IS XACML policy how to validate role and its permissions

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, alfa, wso2-identity-server

In wso2 identity server how to add custom permission like for a role useroperation associate permissions create,update,delete. How can I create the permissions like this.

How can use those assigned permissions for validating by using roles and permissions in XACML policy.

I have created a XACML policy using `Standard Policy Editor` based on the subject name which is username I am fetching role attribute and I am validating, but how can I validate the permissions assoicated to it using XACML. Is it possible to achieve this usecase in wso2 XACML policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways that you can add custom permissions to the WSO2 Identity Server. These methods are given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60445261).

There is a XACML function as **urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:eval-permission-tree** defined in the WSO2 Identity Server. This can be used to validate the permissions of a user.
This function requires two inputs.

1. required permission string (ex: /permission/admin/login)

2. subject or the user whose permissions are validated

In the WSO2 Identity Server, there is a sample XACML policy on using this function. If you login to the management console of the Identity Server, the sample is with the name **evaluate_permission_tree_policy** at *Main > Entitlement > PAP > Policy Administration*

You can get the permission string by referring to the registry of the Identity Server via *Main > Registry > Browse*

I assume that you want to validate the permissions of a given role from the XACML policy. As per the current implementation, the function eval-permission-tree only checks whether the given user is authorized. [1]
To achieve your requirement, you can write your own XACML function extending the EvalPermissionTreeFunction class.
This blog[2] describes how you can write a custom XACML function and plug it into WSO2 IS.

[1] https://github.com/wso2/carbon-identity-framework/blob/master/components/entitlement/org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/entitlement/extension/EvalPermissionTreeFunction.java#L77

[2] https://pamodaaw.medium.com/custom-xacml-functions-for-wso2-identity-server-5-10-0-a91bc2ec673d

Comment: thanks for the reply!!, but if I want to search the permission based on the role how can achieve if I have permission called company_operation under that create,update,view is there which is assigned to a multiple roles like for createuser,createpolicy etc,. In that case how can I query like user role which is having permission create/view/update etc,.